# $S$ and $Q$ are situated in opposite regions with respect to $PR$ in $\triangle PQR$ ,What is the length of $QS$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, analytic-geometry, rectangles

I am currently working on an Olympiad math problem, and I am struggling to find a solution. I would greatly appreciate your help in solving this problem. I was unable to solve the problem because I couldn't use this condition of the length of $PS = 20$ and $ST = 15$. Besides, I don't understand What possible strategies or formulas can be used to solve this problem?
Then how can I suppose to get the value of $QS$.

*A small hint will be enough for me to proceed.*

***Source:*** Bangladesh Math Olympiad *(BDMO)*

> In triangle  $\triangle PQR$, $\angle R= 90^\circ$ and $QR = 21$.  $T$ is a point on the side $PR$ such that $RT = 47$. $S$ and $Q$ are situated in opposite regions with respect to $PR$ in such a way so that  $\angle PST = 90^\circ$ .If $PS = 20$, $ST = 15$ find the length of $QS$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Another User
   Thanks for your kind information, Sir. As a beginner, it was really unknown to me. I always keep that in mind next time

Comment: What is O? The origin? O is just Q?

Comment: thanks for the nice observation. it was a little print mistake & I'm sorry for that... @Mick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. PT = … = 25. Then, RP = 47 + 25.

[image]

2. QP = … = 75.
3. Find $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
4. Apply cosine law to ......

Comment: thanks, brother.....it's so helpful, now I can figure it out...It's 65 may be

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $PT=25$ (Pythagorean triple). Extend $QR$ and project $S$ onto $QR$. Let's say $V$ is the projected point. To find $QS$, we need to find $VS$ and $VR$. Project $T$ onto line $RS$ and use similarity of triangles $PST$ and the newly formed right triangle.

Comment: thanks, it's a nice hint.....it's so helpful, and now I can figure it out...It's 65 may be